# MSBuild using %(RecursiveDir) as part of file name

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

As part of our build script we copy user messages files from a subdirectory and want to append the name of the subdirectory to the message files. 
i.e. msg\0\message.std > msg\message0.std

I have tried using

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(MessageFiles)" 
DestinationFiles="@(MessageFiles->'$(BuildRoot)\%(Filename)%(RecursiveDir)%(Extension)'"/>
```

However this tries to copy the file to ..\message0.std.

Is there anyway to either suppress the trailing '\' from %(RecursiveDir) or make up the destination name another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
<Target Name="DoIt">
    <ItemGroup>
        <MessageFiles2 Include="@(MessageFiles)">
            <SubDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(%(MessageFiles.RecursiveDir)))))</SubDir>
        </MessageFiles2>
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <Message Text="@(MessageFiles2->'$(BuildRoot)\%(Filename)%(SubDir)%(Extension)')"/>
    
</Target>
```

or if you wish to blow up the mind of the person who'll try to maintain your work:

```
<Target Name="DoIt">
    <Message Text="@(MessageFiles->'$(BuildRoot)\%(Filename)$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($([System.String]::Copy('%(MessageFiles.RecursiveDir)'))))))%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```

This is not a complete solution, but you can start from here. Also note that both above examples will break if `RecursiveDir` is empty i.e. your message file lies directly at the root folder.
You can find more information in [MSBuild Property Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions) blog post.

As an another way to handle your problem you can always create [Custom Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx).

Comment: "**if you wish to blow up the mind of the person who'll try to maintain your work**" :-D